# Using ActiveRecord with DelegateClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using rails 3.2.8 I have a model setup with a couple attributes

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :foo, :bar
end
```

I have another class setup using the above as a delegate class

```
class MyModelPresenter < DelegateClass(MyModel)
  def initialize(month, obj)
    @month = month
    super(obj)
  end

  def self.build(month, attributes = { })
    new(month, MyModel.new).tap do |p|
      p.attributes = attributes
    end
  end

  def attributes=(attributes)
    attributes.each { |k, v| send("#{k}=", v) }
  end
end
```

When I create a new MyModelPresenter like so:

```
MyModelPresenter.build(Date.today, {:foo => 1})
```

I get the following back

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo=' for #<MyModel:0x1098f31a8>
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:404:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/me/dev/temp/app/presenters/my_model_presenter.rb:23:in `send'
    from /Users/me/dev/temp/app/presenters/my_model_presenter.rb:23:in `attributes='
    from /Users/me/dev/temp/app/presenters/my_model_presenter.rb:23:in `each'
    from /Users/me/dev/temp/app/presenters/my_model_presenter.rb:23:in `attributes='
    from /Users/me/dev/temp/app/presenters/my_model_presenter.rb:17:in `build'
    from /Users/me/dev/temp/app/presenters/my_model_presenter.rb:15:in `tap'
    from /Users/me/dev/temp/app/presenters/my_model_presenter.rb:15:in `build'
```

For some reason the database attributes on the model aren't getting defined (setters or getters). Before upgrading to rails 3.2 this was all working in a rails 3.1 app.

Does anyone have any idea why the model's attribute methods aren't getting defined?

Comment: Don't know anything about DelegateClass and I have to run so just a comment: AR's accessor and mutator methods are built on the fly via [`method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) (AFAIK) so they don't exist until you try to use them, I think there is some [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) trickery involved as well.

Comment: @muistooshort interestingly if I create a MyModelPresenter without any attributes `p = MyModelPresenter.build(Date.today, {})` I can call `p.respond_to?(:foo=)` and it returns `true`. But then if I try using `p.foo= 1` I get the same error as above. In the error you can see it is hitting the `method_missing` of activerecord. I noticed activerecord's `method_missing` first checks if attributes are defined before trying attribute methods. Since attributes appear to be defined, I'm guessing it probably shouldn't be hitting method_missing at all.

Comment: activerecord's `method_missing`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L122

Comment: And Delegator's `method_missing`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html#method-i-method_missing Could they be fighting each other? Skip down a little bit in the Rails source and you'll see the `respond_to?` trickery (which Delegator will end up using to know if it should delegate or punt to `super`). And which Ruby version are you using with your 3.2 app? How about with your 3.1 version?

Comment: @muistooshort thank you for your comments. For both rails apps I'm using ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from `Delegator` instead of using `DelegateClass` solved the problem. Here is what the final class looked like:

```
class MyModelPresenter < Delegator
  def initialize(month, obj)
    @month = month
    super(obj)
    @_sd_obj = obj
  end

  def __getobj__
    @_sd_obj
  end

  def self.build(month, attributes = { })
    new(month, MyModel.new).tap do |p|
      p.attributes = attributes
    end
  end

  def attributes=(attributes)
    attributes.each { |k, v| send("#{k}=", v) }
  end
end
```

As you can see I also had to add the `def __getobj__` method. and set `@_sd_obj` in the initializer to an instance of the class I'm delegating from.

See the [`SimpleDelegator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) example.

Comment: If you look inside `DelegateClass` you'll see `methods = superclass.instance_methods` so it looks like `DelegateClass` ask the target what methods it has **right now** and bypasses all the `missing_method` trickery completely. This would imply that `DelegateClass` is useless for delegating to anything that uses `method_missing` to automatically create methods. Maybe I'll try a few experiments after work and see if I'm reading things right.